# How to execute a bunch of queries against a particular database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a .sql file which has many create table statements.But some of them are needed to be executed on one database ex:-DB1 and some on another ex:-DB2.how can i specify names of databases so that query gets fired on specified database.

I have found two options

```
 create table DB1.dbo.Tablename(ID INT)
 create table DB2.dbo.Tablename(ID INT)
```

and

```
use DB1
GO
create table dbo.Tablename(ID INT)
GO
```

Is there any other way so that i can assign the name of particular database to a bunch of queries once and queries get executed on that particular database?

Comment: How many options do you need?

Comment: I would go with option one, just because option 2 gives you a better chance of mistakenly create a table in the wrong database.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to separate your file to two (or more) `.sql` file and use the second option for each file.